# Excel: How to calculate movement across columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, finance

I have a dataset where an amount can move forward any number of columns, backwards any number of columns, can be removed or added.

I want to find the balance only, of those that have moved forwards and backwards, disregarding those who have been added or removed. For example in row f below that although a 100 balance was added to column 4, I only want the balance of the 300 that moved from column 3 to column 2.

Current Week:

| ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 0 | 500 | 0 | 0 |
| c | 300 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| d | 1200 | 200 | 100 | 0 |
| e | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| f | 200 | 300 | 0 | 100 |

Last Week:

| ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| b | 500 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| c | 300 | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| d | 1200 | 0 | 100 | 200 |
| e | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| f | 200 | 0 | 300 | 0 |

For some reason the second table just doesn't want to work so here is a picture:

[image]

### List of Movements are below:

a: Pulled forward from 4 -> 1: 100
b: Pushed from 1 -> 2: 500
c: Pulled: 100
d: Pulled: 200
e: Pushed: 100
f: Pulled: 300

### Output

This is what I would expect the output to look like in the end:

Pulled: 700
Pushed: 600

Thank you in advance and anymore question let me know!

Comment: This seems quite tricky! How many rows and columns would there be in practice? Is a VBA solution acceptable? Are there any limits on the size of each (non-zero) number?

Comment: @TomSharpe there would be exactly 7 columns as it is an operational tracker that moves week on week. Each column is a month in the future apart from the first two columns which are inception to date and this month. VBA is fine if possible but I would like a dataset out of this weekly to visualise. Number pushed out (decelleration) number pulled forward (acceleration). The size will generally be less than 3 million and never negative. Thank you

Comment: There are between 200 and 6,000 rows

Comment: OK, that's helpful. Are there the same number of rows, in the same order, in the previous week as in the current week (as in your sample data), or would you have to do a lookup on the ID column? I'm thinking the easiest approach is a separate formula per pair of rows - would then need a couple of helper columns to store the push/pull counts per pair of rows.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks Tom. The rows will be different each week but I don't need the granular detail of which unique ID moved forward and backwards each week, just the total. The order is based on the value so the order will not be consistent. My current method is just to go through them manually, see what has moved out and see what has moved forward and then tally up that way but it is very time consuming.

Comment: What I mean by not needing the granular detail is that it could potentially take the sum at the bottom and see what has moved forwards and what has moved back wards, but this needs to deduct the new additions and removals from the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start as simple as possible. Just assume for now that the rows are in the same order and that you don't mind helper columns. Then you can just use Match to see where the matching amount has moved to:

```
=SUM((MATCH(B13:E13,B3:E3,0)<COLUMN(B:E)-1)*B13:E13)
```

and

```
=SUM((MATCH(B13:E13,B3:E3,0)>COLUMN(B:E)-1)*B13:E13)
```

just pull them down and add them up

[image]

It will need some error handling later for the case where there is no match

Comment: This is perfect Tom!! You are a lifesaver thank you